# Why does the comparison function given to qsort() need to return three different values?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have read that the comparison function required by `qsort()` needs to have 3 outcomes:

- a negative result if `val1 < val2`
- `0` if `val1 == val2`
- a positive result if `val1 > val2`

As far as I know, sorting an array only requires a predicate that returns true or false. Take bubble sort for example:

```
int compare(int a, int b)
{
    if(a>b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
        for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
            if ( compare(arr[j],arr[j+1]) ) 
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}
```

So why does the `qsort()` comparison function need to have 3 possible outcomes and not 2?

Comment: IMO, this is related to the bad habit to perform binary searches as ternary searches, with early termination in case of equality. In most cases, this is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @Matteo Italia, there is an efficiency issue in the number of comparison and you can reduce the number of comparison using the equality as  `a == b` and `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` are equivalent in some cases (for example when the values are integer).

Also, in more general case (not in qsort specifically as mentioned in comments), you need it for stability of the sort function. In equality cases, if the sort wants to be stable, it should know about the equality in the comparison. You can know more about the stabilty in sorting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).
Hence, **three value return is required for stable sort methods**.

Comment: It must be noted that (1) `qsort` is not stable and (2) it's not strictly required, but just an optimization - if you only have a "less than" operator, you can deduce the equality by using two comparisons (`a == b` <-> `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`).

Comment: @MatteoItalia `(a == b <-> !(a < b) && !(b < a))` is not certainly  true when `a,b` are floating point and a value may be not-a-number.

Comment: `qsort()` is not specified to be stable.

Comment: @chux NaNs with regular IEEE754 `<` break pretty much any required property of a strict weak ordering, so, while your statement is of course technically correct, it's not really relevant to a discussion regarding sorting.

Comment: More in general, the `<` and `==` in my previous comment aren't to be intended literally as the C operators - heck they would make no sense even just for strings -, but as the comparison operators induced by a given ordering relation suitable for sorting, i.e. a strict weak ordering.

Comment: A 3-way sort is pretty much required for a stable sort.  While technically correct, it's not really relevant to a discussion why with `qsort()`, "is it really necessary?".

Comment: @chux it could be related and could be an extra point which could inspire the OP to explore more around his question.

Comment: True, The relevancy of requirements of a 3-way sort are a [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791771/qsort-comparator-function-is-is-it-really-necessary-to-return-0/53791861?noredirect=1#comment94441607_53791861) for OP to explore - just like the issues of `(a == b <-> !(a < b) && !(b < a))` with FP math are [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791771/qsort-comparator-function-is-is-it-really-necessary-to-return-0/53791861?noredirect=1#comment94439474_53791861) to explore with sorting.

Comment: There may be some specific sorting algorithm for which a 3 valued comparison simplifies achieving stability, but that's not the norm: quicksort isn't stable regardless of 2 vs. 3 valued comparison function; and mergesort is stable with just a 2-valued function.

As far as I can tell in most real-world cases, sorting algorithms using 2-valued comparison functions appear to be faster or at least no slower than the more complex algorithms permitted by a 3-valued comparison.

Answer (score 5):

`qsort` could be written using a boolean compare function instead of a three-way compare but the specification says that it takes a three-way compare function and some (not all) implementations take advantage of the three possible cases. If your compare function doesn't conform to the specification,  Undefined Behaviour will result. In this case, Undefined Behaviour might include a failure to sort correctly or a buffer overrun triggered on very rare corner cases, which you might not notice until the space shuttle is returning from orbit. So don't do that.

As to why an implementation might want the three-way comparison, here is one possibility: for inputs with a lot of repeated values, quicksort can be speeded up considerably by using a three-way partition. That can be done with a two-way comparison by doing the comparison twice in opposite directions, but an implementor, knowing that a three-way comparator is required, is likely to test for equality when that's what they want to know.

Answer (score 3):

If element A `==` element B but the comparator function tells `qsort` that `B > A` then `qsort` will think there may be other elements which should be between `A` and `B` when that is not the case, and therefore perform unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can do with just less-than, because `a == b` is equivalent to `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`.

Comment: Independently of Matteo's comment. ;-)

Comment: That is, assuming full ordering. Seems obvious as we are sorting, but it's important to remember that equivalence does not hold in the general case.

Comment: `a == b` is equivalent to !`(a < b) && !(b < a)` is not always true with FP math.

Comment: @chux: do you have an example ?

Comment: @yves: if at least one of `a` and `b` is NaN, all comparisons return `false`. But `!false && !false` is `true`.

Comment: `a < NaN` returning `false` instead of `NaN` is a mistake in history.

Comment: @yvesDaoust: So was the Boer War, but there it is. (ambiguously signed `char` is way ahead on my list :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, comparison returning NaN? How would that work? If you did `if (a < b)` and `b` happened to be NaN, the program would still need to decide if it should run the conditional block or not...

Comment: @ilkkachu: hehe, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the quicksort inner loop is written equivalent to this:

```
while(x[i] < pivot) i++;  // less-than
while(pivot < x[j]) j--;  // less-than
```

then you can get away with only implementing `<`.

In any case, stick to the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) by making it more obvious what the caller is supposed to do -- if your compare function pointer is named `compare` and the function shouldn't behave like a usual stdlib `qsort` compare delegate, then it's a bad idea.

On the other hand, if your parameter is named something like `less_than` or `isLessThan`, it should be much more obvious to the caller what is expected from the comparison function:

```
 void sort(
     const void * arr,
     size_t num_items,
     size_t element_size, 
     bool (*is_less_than)(const void*, const void*)
 );
```